# Would separate Entities help reduce the memory consumed? (Entity Framework)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure

We have a big accounting project, containing 300+ tables.

Then, we have different modules - Finance, Checkroll, etc.

Currently, each module is loading a giant Edmx entity containing all those tables. It is so clunky that it loads a very long time just to add a column into that Edmx.

So, I suggest to separate the entities. Ideally, each Module should only contain the tables that belong to him. Hopefully with this, it could minimize memory usage at the server.

Then, as expected, some reject the ideas. They claim that it doesn't help much (reduce server load / reduce Memory consumed) by saying that the Linq works like lazyload - "if you don't use the table in your linq query, it won't consume the extra memory."

I would like to justify whether that statement is valid. How's your practice normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to minimize memory consumption use smaller DbContexts, and use gcServer setting (if you run a console app or Windows Servce) - there are also other things you can do, see the MSDN whitepaper, [Performance Considerations for EF 4, 5, and 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: That's a informative link. I would like to ask, when you mentioned 'smaller DbContexts', do you mean separating the entities into different database? Currently we have only 1, a giant one.

Comment: @zflaw No, I mean splitting entities into a number of DbContexts, each with their own area of interest

Comment: By saying smaller DbContexts, would that mean it contains lesser tables? (sorry i am not sure which is the proper term). That is to say, different modules contain its own DbContext, instead of using one big one (which contains everything inside the database)